# How to select multiple columns with JQuery to populate another control on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with an HTML table and a select element. I want to use jQuery to extract two columns each row of the able, and add the columns as entries in the select list. For example, if my table is:

1   apple   extra
2   banana  extra
3   cherry  extra

Then when the page loads I would like to add three labels to the select, one for each fruit name, with the corresponding values determined by the first column. I have unsuccessfully attempted to solve this at http://jsfiddle.net/dcodelli/7Ez9d/

My code:

```
$(document).ready
(
    function()
    {
        
        var allindexes = $('#Fruits> tbody > tr > td:nthchild(1)').map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
            }).get();

        var allnames = $('#Fruits> tbody > tr > td:nthchild(1)').map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
            }).get();
        
            
        for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
            $('#Preset').append('<option value = \"' + allindexes[index] + 
                                '\">"' + allnames[index] + '</option>');
}
    }
    
);
```

Comment: What the heck?  You aren't terminating the quoted string on line 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$(document).ready
(
       $('table#Fruits > tbody > tr').each(function(trIndex) {
           console.log ("tr");
           var sText;
           $(this).find('td').each (function(index, data) {
               console.log(data);
               if (index == 1) {
                   sText = $(this).html();
               }
           });
           $('#PreSet').append("<option value='" +trIndex+ "'>" + sText + "</option>");
      })
)
```

Many issues with your jsfiddle including wrong table name, wrong dropdown id.

Comment: That works!  Thanks so much, and sorry for the sloppy first pass.

Comment: Glad to hear, it was a bit of an exercise for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Using your JSFiddle as a base (see JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dualspiral/6XdPm/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var allindexes = $('#Fruits > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)').map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    var allnames = $('#Fruits > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)').map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    for (index = 0; index < allindexes.length; ++index) {
        $('#PreSet').append('<option value = "' + allindexes[index] + '">' + allnames[index] + '</option>');
    }
});
```

You were using the wrong selector for nth-child (you missed out the hyphen), and in your for loop, you used the wrong variable (`a.length` instead of `allindexes.length`). Your JSFiddle also did not have the right ID for the dropdown (PreSet is not the same as Preset).